# how can i disable a specific collision in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-editor

hi i was making a multiplayer game where at some point the bullet was colliding with the sender and i don't want that. It keeps making glitches and the bullet keeps floating. I even tried reducing the player box collider but its still getting stuck. if i disable collision detection for the player and the bullet, the multiplayer version will be affected and players won't be dying

Please help

tried to reduce the player collider but when the bullet is shot on y axis its getting stuck

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing a multiplayer game, On the client side you could change the player's object layer to something unique. In my case here, I've added a new layer called **Player** and I'm instantiating my player on a layer called **Enemy** by default. I'm also putting my bullets on a layer called **Bullet**.
[image: fig0]

Make sure you only change the layer from **Enemy** to **Player** on the client side at runtime and for your client's player object only.
Then you can go into **Edit/Project Settings/Physics** and scroll down to the bottom until you find a collision truth table.
[image: fig1]

Then ensure that you uncheck the collisions between your player's layer and bullet's layer.